# create material in unity with sprite picture

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to create material from this shape:

[image: this shape]

for 
Deformed like the image above.But I do not know how to make such materials in Unity

Answer (score 12):

You just have to import your picture(of shape you want) into unity. (Drag and drop it there) Then click Assets -> Create -> Material
Then, under Main Maps, you should see an option called Albedo with a gray square to its left. Drag your picture into this square.
[image]

Comment: This is what answers should look like.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**in Project Tab:**

- Create Material
- Set the shader to Unlit/Transparent
- Apply your sprite to material.

**In Hierarchy Tab:**

- Create Quad
- Apply Material to Quad.

Comment: no my friends that dont work for me in next replay show after use your solution

Comment: - set the texture type as "Sprite 2D/UI" with sprite mode to Single. Then add it in the hierarchy as a Sprite and not a 3D textured Quad / Plane.